# mongodb array updates in python script

Tags: python, mongodb, updates

I need to update values in array `jobs` in mongo collection by python script

for example, the following works perfectly fine in mongo console, but how to do so in python

```
posts.update({'_id':213},{'$set':{"jobs.1.title":1}}, false, true)
```

one more interesting point, I thought by using `$` I can change all values in array. The following neither works in console nor in script.

```
posts.update({'_id':213},{'$set':{"jobs.$.title":1}}, false, true)
```

The question is how can I do the above updates in python script.

Comment: Are you using pymongo to work with mongodb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very similar in Python's pymongo [`update`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update):

```
posts.update({'_id':213}, {'$set':{"jobs.1.title":1}}, upsert=False, multi=True)
```

Of course, you also need to connect to the database and set `posts` to that collection.

[`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/) does not act as a wildcard like you are thinking; it identifies the first array element in the doc that matches the query.  I don't think there's a way to update all array elements like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) to interact with MongoDB from python.

Regarding the $ operator to update all the values in an array, it is not how you are supposed to use it. Please check the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_).

> The array field must appear as part of the query selector.

There is an [open issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) on the MongoDB issue tracker regarding this topic.

A workaround would be to read the document, change the array values program side and update it.